# Reading pixel colors from PNG file without any outsourced lib (Windows 11)

Tags: c++, image, byte, png, steganography

So I'm trying to read PNG file, what I have a problem with is, how to read pixels. I know how to read bytes etc. but i don't know how to recognize which values are resposible for colors.
From what I undersand outside of the headers, there are chunk types, first few bytes of a chunk tell how long data will be, but then I don't know which bytes in this data represent colors.

Comment: You need to know the [file format](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/) and parse the file. Btw, _why_ not use a free library for this? It seems to be a lot of work to do it from scratch.

Comment: What platform are you on?  Windows' GDIPlus, for example, can parse png files directly.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, btw. great site, somehow I missed it while googling png. So form what i understand and read, I need to adjust my code based on "bit depth" byte.

Comment: Oh, I'm on windows 11, forgot to mention.

Comment: @TedLyngmo well i need it for my CS class, little steganography project, I needed to choose 2 formats, I already implemented BMP (easy one) but now I have a problem with PNG.

Comment: PNG RGB is compressed using the Deflate compression algorithm. You need to decompress it first than read the data. It is quite complex.

Comment: The format specification for PNG is here: [https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#4Concepts.EncodingCompression](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#4Concepts.EncodingCompression)

Comment: BTW, writing a PNG reader yourself (with no OS api or library) is very far from a simple project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.